# .NET file system wrapper library

Tags: .net, mocking

For some reason I can't find one, but someone must have already created a .NET IO library wrapper.  I want to be able to mock calls to File.Exists etc, and the static methods builtin don't lend well to this.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "the static methods built in don't lend well to this." What functionality are you looking for that .NET doesn't provide?

Comment: dependency injection, mocking and anything else that is very hard with static methods and classes

Answer (score 10):

I found [SystemWrapper](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/) a few minutes before yours, but yours suits my purposes better.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a [FileInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx), which does the same things as the static methods.

On the other hand, you probably don't want to mock the entirety of the FileInfo class. Instead, you want to place all of your file operations into a single class, then extract an interface from the class (describing the public methods), and use the interface to mock the file operations that *you* perform, not the entire set of operations that Microsoft thinks should be in the FileInfo class.

Answer (score 3):

All good answers, but they all left me where I started - recreating some sort of IFileSystem for every project I end up working on.  I ended up creating a generic [IFileSystem](http://code.google.com/p/sneal/source/browse/trunk/Core/Sneal.Core/IO/IFileSystem.cs) library around the .NET libraries that I can use reuse between all my projects.  Not great, but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain the [Jolt.NET](http://jolt.codeplex.com) project on CodePlex, which contains a library to generate such interfaces and their implementations for you.  Please refer to the [Jolt.Testing](http://jolt.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Jolt.Testing) library for more information.

Comment: More people would use it if you move to Github and create a Nuget package. I don't even take a closer look just because of that...

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions allows you to do this (example from github)

```
public class MyComponent
{
readonly IFileSystem fileSystem;

// <summary>Create MyComponent with the given fileSystem implementation</summary>
public MyComponent(IFileSystem fileSystem)
{
    this.fileSystem = fileSystem;
}
/// <summary>Create MyComponent</summary>
public MyComponent() : this( 
    fileSystem: new FileSystem() //use default implementation which calls System.IO
) 
{
}

public void Validate()
{
    foreach (var textFile in fileSystem.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        var text = fileSystem.File.ReadAllText(textFile);
        if (text != "Testing is awesome.")
            throw new NotSupportedException("We can't go on together. It's not me, it's you.");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for a library that wraps the whole filesystem.   Why not create a simple IFileSystem interface and start adding the methods that you need.

The rest of your application should depend on IFileSystem which  will allow for mocking

You can have one implementation that simply calls the static methods that .Net gives you and then your code can depend on the interface.

Comment: This is what I've done in the past, but I get tired of continually re-creating this interface in every project I work on.  Looking for a little code re-use here.

Comment: put it in a shared library and reference it in all of your projects

Comment: I guess Sneal is thinkg "but why create your own if you can grab some open source and probably more mature project than your in-house solution". It's about NOT re-inventing the wheel.