# Mock File.Exists method in Unit Test (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET file system wrapper library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738084/net-file-system-wrapper-library)

I would like to write a test where the content of a file get's loaded. In the example the class which is used to load the content is

```
FileClass
```

and the method

```
GetContentFromFile(string path).
```

Is there any way to mock the

```
File.exists(string path)
```

method in the given example with moq?

Example:

I have a class with a method like that:

```
public class FileClass 
{
   public string GetContentFromFile(string path)
   {
       if (File.exists(path))
       {
           //Do some more logic in here...
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: download systemwrapper: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/SystemWrapper.shtml

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Most of the time, you shouldn't use File.Exists() in the first place.  It's much better to just open the file and handle the exception if it fails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the Exists method is a static method on the File class, you can't mock it (see note at bottom). The simplest way to work around this is to write a thin wrapper around the File class. This class should implement an interface that can be injected into your class.

```
public interface IFileWrapper {
    bool Exists(string path);
}

public class FileWrapper : IFileWrapper {
    public bool Exists(string path) {
        return File.Exists(path);
    }
}
```

Then in your class:

```
public class FileClass {
   private readonly IFileWrapper wrapper;

   public FileClass(IFileWrapper wrapper) {
       this.wrapper = wrapper;
   }

   public string GetContentFromFile(string path){
       if (wrapper.Exists(path)) {
           //Do some more logic in here...
       }
   }
}
```

**NOTE:** [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/) allows you to mock static methods. Other popular frameworks, e.g. Moq, Rhino Mocks, etc, don't.

Comment: I think you made a typo.

if (wrapper.FileExists(path)) {
           //Do some more logic in here...
       }

Should just be a call to wrapper.Exists

Comment: It's also worth noting that since this answer was originally written, Microsoft added capabilities similar to TypeMock as part of Visual Studio -- it's called the Fakes framework.